# OpenGL QMatrix4x4 get matrix values

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QMatrix4x4`, which I apply a few operations to like `rotate(degree, QVector3D(x,y,z))` and `translate(x,y,z)`

How do I find output the matrix values?

Comment: Are you trying to just read the values or do you want f.i. to set it as a shader uniform? QOpenGLShaderProgram has builtin support for setting a QMatrix4x4 as a uniform...

Comment: @peppe I'm a beginner to openGL, I am trying to make a cube. I want to read the values in standard output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data()` function to get a pointer to the raw data which you can pass into the `glUniformMatrix4fv`.